# AWS Sagemker debugger examples TypeError missing argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, typeerror, amazon-sagemaker

**TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'action_str'**

The error pops up in the official example jupyter notebook (**mnist_tensor_analysis.ipynb**) of the amazon Sagemaker debugger. Occurs when calling the constructor of the Rule package from smdebug.rules.rule.
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O00Um.jpg)

Are there any solutions to this problem? The error is visible in the official repo of the AWS Sagemaker debugger. Below is the link to the notebook.

link : https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-debugger/mnist_tensor_analysis/mnist_tensor_analysis.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from a breaking change in the smdebug library. The notebook is tested with an older version of smdebug (v1.0.0). The fix is coming in this [PR](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/pull/3192). In the mean time, if you change the code cell for installing the library to

!  python -m pip install -U smdebug==1.0.0

the notebook should work fine.